# Does Meta Spark AR Studio support tracking of hand tilting?

Tags: spark-ar-studio

I have been trying to make an effect that makes a spinning saw blade on your hand. It does appear, however, when my hand tilts, the saw blade 3D object does not rotate with my hand. Is there any ways that I can make it detect? I am making this as an Instagram effect.

I did look for videos on youtube, but all of them just talked about how I can make an object that moves with my hand, but none of them can detect the rotation of a hand.